# How to set an array element wtih a sequence?

Tags: python

My question is very simple. I have center value and a radius value. I want to put these values into centers and radius arrays seperately.

```
centers[0][i], radius[0][i] = cv.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i])
```

when I run my code I got "Setting an array element with a sequence" in this line.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random as rng
rng.seed(12345)

threshold = 100
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Code for Creating Bounding boxes and circles for contours tutorial.')
parser.add_argument('--input', help='Path to input image.', default='stuff.jpg')
args = parser.parse_args()
src = cv.imread('training3.jpg')
if src is None:
    print('Could not open or find the image:', args.input)
    exit(0)
# Convert image to gray and blur it
src_gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
src_gray = cv.blur(src_gray, (3,3))
source_window = 'Source'
cv.namedWindow(source_window)
cv.imshow(source_window, src)
canny_output = cv.Canny(src_gray, threshold, threshold * 2)

contours, _ = cv.findContours(canny_output, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours_poly = [None]*len(contours)
boundRect = [None]*len(contours)
centers = np.zeros([2,len(contours)])
radius = np.zeros([1,len(contours)])

for i, c in enumerate(contours):
   contours_poly[i] = cv.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
   boundRect[i] = cv.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
   centers[0][i], radius[0][i] = cv.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i])
```

Inside of cv.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i]) is:

```
cv.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[0]) = ((688.5, 958.5), 2.9155757427215576)
```

For instance, I want to get these results:

```
centers[0] =  (688.5, 958.5)
radius[0] = 2.9155757427215576
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Your problem is currently not reproducible. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example

Comment: The error message is absolutely clear. You can't assign `centers[0][i] = (688.5, 958.5)` since numpy doesn't allow you to assign tuple to np.array item.

Comment: Thank you for your help.